# How can i get username fron fabric-client , where name set in registerUser.js?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

My objective is to show username in web page, where I create user using the following code.

```
 return fabric_client.createUser(
     {username: 'user1',
     mspid: 'Org1MSP',
     cryptoContent: { privateKeyPEM: enrollment.key.toBytes(), signedCertPEM: enrollment.certificate }
     });
```

I couldn't find the way to get the username.

Comment: For future posts, it would be helpful if you linked to the specific function that you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're calling the [Client.createUser](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/Client.html#createUser__anchor) function. It returns (asynchronously) a [User](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/User.html) object which has a [getName()](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/User.html#getName__anchor) function. Looking at the docs and source, it would appear that the user `name` field is used to store the username.

Take special note that the function is async, meaning that it returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that will resolve to a `User`.